# Why Button is not showing in javascript

Tags: javascript, django, button

In my project, button not showing in frontend. what can i do for showing the button???

```js
function updatePopover(product_cart){
  console.log('we are in updatePopover');
  var popStr = "";
  popStr = popStr + "<h5>cart for your items</h5> <div class='mx-2 my-2'>";
  var i =1;
  for (var item in product_cart){
    popStr = popStr + "<b>" + i + "</b>. ";
    popStr = popStr + document.getElementById('name' + item).innerHTML.slice(0, 25) + "... Qty: " + product_cart[item] + '<br>';
    i = i+1;
  }
  popStr = popStr + "</div> <a href='/checkout' class='btn_1' id='checkout'>CheckOut</a> **<button 
  class='btn_1' onclick='clearCart()'>Clear Cart</button><button class='btn btn-primary'></button>** "
  document.getElementById("popcarts").setAttribute('data-content', popStr);
  $('#popcarts').popover('show');
}
```

Comment: this is because there is no HTML to display anything...  https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: I think there is a line break after `<button ` in **<button class='btn_1' onclick='clearCart()'>Clear Cart</button><button class='btn btn-primary'></button>**. Try to remove line break after <button

Answer (score 0):

Accually i solved the problem. I faced the problem becouse of version of bootstrap. i used bootsrap 4.3 to make the project, but when i add popover feature, i take bootstrap v5 popover. Thats way, in the popover button is not showing.

Solution : Use same version of bootstrap for popover.